# How to avoid duplicate items being added from one CheckBoxList to another CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net

While adding items from one `CheckBoxList` to another `CheckBoxList` how to check if the item is already present in the second `CheckBoxList` using asp.net c#

The code I have written to move between `CheckBoxLists` is:

```
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= CheckBoxList2.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList2.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(CheckBoxList2.Items[i]);
                CheckBoxList3.ClearSelection();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using **add_Click** button to move items between lists.
I need to validate while adding items.

Kindly help. Thank you..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :-

```
for (int i = 0; i <= CheckBoxList2.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList2.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                CheckBoxList4.Items.Add(CheckBoxList2.Items[i].ToString().Trim());

            }
        }

foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList4.Items)
        {
            if (!CheckBoxList3.Items.Contains(item))
            {
                CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

quote from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760723/931049) by @Joel-Coehoorn:

> You need a using directive for System.Linq. .Where() is an extension method on IEnumerable (which IList implements) that is defined in the System.Linq namespace.

first take all the selected items

```
var checkedItems = CheckBoxList2.Items.Where(i => i.Selected);
```

and then iterate through.

```
foreach(var item in checkedItems)
{
   if(!CheckBoxList3.Items.Contains(item))
   {
       CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(item)
   }
}
```

that should be fine.

Comment: If CheckBoxList3 contains item, then you adding it ?

Comment: well spotted - I'd missed the `!` to invert the boolean :)

Comment: This is giving me an error : Error 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: a reference to Linq extension methods is required - apologies, I'm just used to Linq always being there now.

Comment: :( - what about he slightly ugly addition of a .ToList() `var checkedItems = CheckBoxList2.Items.ToList().Where(i => i.Selected);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17002/discussion-between-chris-and-archana-b-r)

Answer (score 0):

without using a third CheckBoxList..(modified the above ans)

```
 foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            if (!CheckBoxList2.Items.Contains(li))
            {
                CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(li);  
            }
        }

    }
```