# How can I prevent copying of duplicate items from one CheckBoxList to another CheckBoxList on Button_Click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two checkboxlists. First one have few items already and second is unbound. I want to add the checked items of first checkboxlist to the second checkboxlist on button click. I'm using for loop for that. But the problem is that when the button is clicked again. It copies duplicate values. How can I prevent this to copy duplicate values? The code on button_click event is as following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
                CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(CheckBoxList1.Items[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/12545718/122005

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`ListItemCollection.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.contains.aspx) method:

```
var toAdd = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                         .Where(li => li.Selected 
                                   && !CheckBoxList2.Items.Contains(li));
foreach(ListItem li in toAdd)
{
    CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq` for this little query above or use a loop instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, It solved my problem. As I'm not much more familiar with C# and .net I just added Items.contains method to my code. Instead of going in details you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough reputation for voting. Is there any other way to accept answer here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at the [Collection.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx) method. I think this will fix your problem. do this before you add it to the second list.

here some pseudo code

```
if(!List.Contains(selectedItem)
{
    Add(selectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Except(System.Linq)

```
        double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
        double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

        IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);

        foreach (double number in onlyInFirstSet)
            Console.WriteLine(number);
```